# Windows Form designer size does no match runtime size

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, windows-forms-designer

First of all, here is an image that will help you understand the problem better
[image: Form Comparison]

As you can see, both the designer form in the background and the debug runtime form are almost perfectly aligned with each other. Yet still, the form on its "normal size" ends up eating "Total" label on its bottton right side. That label and the rest of the form content shows up nicely both on the designer form, and on the MAXIMIZED runtime form, as you can see below.
[image]

So, to summarize, how do i make the normal sized runtime form not eat up my labels that show up just fine on my designer form?

Comment: if designer is not reliable, you can modify the size in **code behind**.

Comment: Does docking it at the bottom also give the same result?

Comment: You mean, docking the label that is being cut? Nope, doesnt help. It Just goes to a very weird location

Comment: No. I mean docking the whole `tabcontrol` form and no need to individually dock each label or anchor them as long as `label` input does not exceed `tabcontrol` size. Additional info, using the layout toolbar will help you in getting a perfectly aligned design to your label in case you haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Docking actualy just made the tabcontrol prettier, but i managed to achieve some results using the layout toolbar. I turned off the labels AutoSize and made their horizontal spacing equal. 

This was the result on the runtime normal size form https://puu.sh/vaPPF/9499ed1da2.png

Now i believe i need to lower the font size of the "black labels" to a font that let its text fit inside the label size, is that it?

Comment: Basically yes and if you still have problems dealing with it at designer side, like what @LeiYang suggested, try going over it in the code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, turns out i didnt knew that each `tabPage` inside the `tabControl` had a property called `AutoScroll` that automatically puts a scrollbar on the tabPage if its contents dont fit the tabpage size.

So i simply turned that property on, set the labels `AutoSize` property back again to `true` and the result did match my expectations.

[image]

Nonetheless, i thank everyone that took their time to try and help me with their knowledge :D

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Anchor` property. Here is the description of it:

> Defines the edge of the container to which a certain control is bound.
>   When a control is anchored to an edge, the distance between the
>   control's closest edge and the specified edge will remain constant.

In this case, you would set the label `Total da Folha Selecionada` Anchor to `Right`.

However, there is no way to show all the labels if there isn't space for it. For that, you could specify a `MinimumSize` for your Form.

Comment: Tried that already, the last label simply melds into the other by using anchor https://puu.sh/vaN01/fe6fa3a724.png

Comment: That is what I said about minimum size: there is simply no space to fit all the labels, so they overlap or disappear. If you don't want to set a MinimumSize you could adjust things programatically, like reducing the size of the labels if a certain `Width` is reached. Let me know if you need help with that!

Comment: Yeah, that idea did indeed pop into my head earlier, but i just wanted to make sure there was really no other way other than managing label font and control sizes.

What REALLY pisses me off is the fact that on the designer the label is drawn JUST FINE https://puu.sh/vaOTo/91d522b66a.png